# Running bash script with parameters from java, starting appium node not working

Tags: java, bash, terminal, appium

I have a problem running a bashscript from java which needs parameters and will start an Appiumnode. So I want a physical terminal open where the node is running.

I managed to start a selenium grid with the following command:

```
rt.exec( new String[] { "/usr/bin/open" , "-a", "Terminal.app", "grid.sh"}) ;
```

whereas the script itself is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/../../usr/local/selenium
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 4040
```

But for the appiumnodes, we have different devices and because of this we have different nodes.
I want to start these with a parametrized script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/../..
node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js --nodeconfig $1 -p $2 -U $3 -bp $4
```

But I'm not able to get the nodes running in the terminals as with the grid.

I've tried many solutions found here and others but none of them with success. All the time, terminal is not opened and no node is started.

Solutions that I've tried are:

```
rt.exec( new String[] { "/usr/bin/open" , "-a", "Terminal.app", "NodeExecutor.sh " + filepath + " "+ Port + " " + parts[1] + " " + bp});
rt.exec( new String[] { "/bin/bash" , "-c", "/bin/bash NodeExecutor.sh " + filepath + " "+ Port + " " + parts[1] + " " + bp});

rt.exec( new String[] { "/usr/bin/open" , "-a", "Terminal.app"});
rt.exec( new String[] { "/usr/bin/osascript" , "-e", "tell application \"Terminal\" to do shell script \""+ filepath + "/NodeExecutor.sh " + filepath + " "+ Port + " " + parts[1] + " " + bp + "\" "});
```

All my bash scripts are also set as executable: `chmod +x /PATH...`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: No, it doesn't return anything. The code is executed but nothing happened.

Comment: Just start to debug your BASH script: insert a line in your "parametrized script" like: echo `"debug: $*" >> /tmp/JonasVandevelde.txt` and check the `JonasVandevelde.txt` text file.

Comment: But the bash works as I tried it through terminal, but from the moment that I try to execute it through java, it fails (or just skips it)